# How to interact between multiple docker containers, eg ubuntu container with selenium hub container

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, mono, dockerfile

I have the following three docker containers
1. Ubuntu Container with Mono that has selenium scripts(DLL)
2. Selenium Hub Container
3. Selenium Chrome Node Container

when I build the Docker Compose File, All three containers are up and running, the Ubuntu container exits after sometime without executing any tests.Any idea on how to implement this?

I am executing the tests in the Ubuntu container using mono and would like to create a docker image once this works. Any explanation or sample code on this would be really great.

I have created a bridge and have assigned static ip to all three containers.

Docker Compose File:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  seleniumhub:
      image: selenium/hub
      container_name: hubcontainer
      networks:
         ynetwork:
           ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
      ports:
         - "4444:4444"
      privileged: true

  nodechrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
      container_name: chromecontainer
      volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      depends_on:
         - seleniumhub
      environment:
         - HUB_HOST=seleniumhub
         - HUB_PORT=4444
         - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
         - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
         - START_XVFB=false
      networks:
         ynetwork:
            ipv4_address: 172.21.0.10

  Mytests:
      container_name: Myubuntutests
      depends_on:
         - seleniumhub
         - nodechrome
      networks:
         ynetwork:
            ipv4_address: 172.21.0.11
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: ubuntu.Dockerfile
networks:
  ynetwork:
      name: ytestsnetwork
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
         config:
         - subnet: 172.21.0.0/16
```

Docker File ubuntu.Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY /bin/Debug/ /MyTests
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Asia/Tokyo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && apt-get update && apt-get clean && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y nuget && apt-get install -y mono-complete && apt-get update && nuget update -self && nuget install testrunner
WORKDIR "/MyTests"
ENTRYPOINT mono /TestRunner.1.8.0/tools/testrunner.exe MyTests.dll
```

```
Docker Compose commands used (tried):
docker-compose up --build
docker-compose up --build -d
```

I expect the Docker Compose to Build all three containers and execute the tests and exit once done

Comment: Can you `docker run` the one container in isolation?  How does it know where the other two containers are?

Comment: I have tried running containers manually in isolation using docker run and it works fine, the only way i am aware of is by adding all containers on the same network, is there some other way also?